# QML Calendar type, forcing the visible year does not work

Tags: qt, qml

This is my code:

```
Rectangle {
    id: calendarPopUp
    visible: false;
    border.width: 0
    color: "#ffffff"
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.top: parent.top
    width: parent.width
    z: 10;
    VMComboBox{
        id: yearPicker
        width: parent.width
        //vmModel: ["1999", "2000"]
        vmModel: {
            var ans = [];
            var cyear = 2018;
            var fyear = cyear - 120;
            for (var i = cyear; i >= fyear; i--){
                ans.push(i)
            }
            calendar.minimumDate = new Date(fyear, 0, 1);
            calendar.maximumDate = new Date(cyear, 0, 1);
            return ans;
        }
        font.family: viewHome.robotoR.name
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 2
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            var year = yearPicker.currentText;
            console.log("Changing visible year to: " + year);
            calendar.visibleYear = parseInt(year);
        }
    }
    Calendar {
        id: calendar
        width: parent.width
        anchors.top: yearPicker.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }
}
```

VMComboBox is a custom combo box. I need this to select birth dates. However, the QML Calendar does not provide for a conformtable way to quickly navigate back in time. I thought that addign a combo box to select the year would be the quickest way.

Howver setting the visibleYear on my calendar element does not change the visible year. It changes the year sometime, but it is almost random. I can't see any relation on the difference between the selected year and shown year.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code could not be run. Please prepeare the code and provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And you should clarify the question. What exactly the problem? What does _It changes the year sometimes_ mean?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on the clock and I can't create a complete example. I had hoped that someone had alreday had to input birth dates with a QML calendar. And it changes the year sometimes, means exactly that. I change the year, no change in the visible year is registered. I change it again, the visible year changes to some year which is not the one I chose. I change it again and it might change or it might not.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've tested the `Calendar` item and I can't reproduce the issue you've told about.
Here is a test code, I guess it will be useful for you.

```js
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as Controls1

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Calendar")
    width: 300
    height: 400
    visible: true

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ComboBox {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: 40
            property int year: new Date().getFullYear()
            model: {
                var arr = [];
                for(var i = year; i > (year - 50); i--)
                    arr.push(i);
                return arr;
            }
            currentIndex: year - calendar.visibleYear
            onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                calendar.visibleYear = year - currentIndex;
            }
        }
        ComboBox {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: 40
            model: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
            currentIndex: calendar.visibleMonth
            onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                calendar.visibleMonth = currentIndex;
            }
        }
        Controls1.Calendar {
            id: calendar
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            navigationBarVisible: false
        }
    }

}
```

Works like a charm.